# How to take the triple integral of $ \iiint_G xy\sin (yz)dV$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I'm trying to evaluate $$\iiint_G xy\sin(yz) \ dV$$ where $G$ is the rectangular box defined by the inequalities $0 ≤ x ≤ \pi, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, 0 ≤ z ≤ \pi/6$.

I wasn't sure where to go after the first integral, since the double integral gets really messy. Would I have to set up an integration by parts from here and then just algebra really well?

Comment: integrating first wrt $z$ cancels out the $y$ factor, so the integral simplifies

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help, this way allowed me to reduce down and get the right answer. I tried it with the dy and it was closer than dx, but then that didn't reduce anything down and I guess I didn't come back to it with a dz.

Answer (score 1):

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/6} \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{\pi} xy\sin (yz) dxdydz$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it this way many times, but I think it doesn't get to be clean since there's integration by parts involved (which is a good review from Calc II, but I'm a little crunched on time today).